# Google Chrome process are sleeping and doing nothing

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium, nagios

I'm using Selenium WebDriver, Google Chrome and Nagios with a Python script that checks a couple of links for a Web site. It works really well, except for one thing: sometimes, the Google Chrome process is still waiting in the background and will stay there until I kill it.

Using strace, I only saw those kind of calls:

```
futex(0x7fffe75b4b48, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
write(20, "\0", 1)                      = 1
```

It's doing that for 3-4 processes per day, while other processes terminates correctly, and I can't see why it's doing that for only a couple of processes.

Comment: Are you doing driver.quit after each test.That usually kills the exe.

Comment: Yes, I do call drive.quit every time, including when exceptions are handled.

Comment: Thats good.I have faced similar issues where I used an external batch script to terminate the processes as a workaround.I am not sure what is the use case for linux.

Comment: I have to do the same thing. I have done a Python scripts that finds any Chrome process who are more than 30 minutes old and kill them.

Comment: That should work for the time being.If you are using TestNG then you can put the cleanup logic in the AfterTest method or something like that,or else you can put it in a method of your own and then make sure that method called after your test ends.I do a lot of cleanup work such killing chrome processes,cleaning temp folders for scoped dir files in that case of  chrome and anonymous profiles in case of firefox and things like that. Lets hope that higher versions of selenium provide these out of the box.